# What is the kernel of the induced map on symmetric algebras?

Tags: commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

Let 
$$0\to M\to N\to P\to 0$$
be an exact sequence of $R$-modules over a commutative ring $R$.Then consider the induced map on the $i^{th}$ graded piece of the symmetric algebras: $$S^i(N)\to S^i(P).$$ What's the kernel?

It's clear that any product $mn_2\ldots n_i$ is in the kernel, where $m\in M$ and each $n_k\in N$. But why is that it?

In this question:

[Symmetric powers of modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90148/symmetric-powers-of-modules)

They mention using right exactness. How specifically is this used? I couldn't find the referenced Bourbaki chapter.

Answer (score 2):

I shall assume your exact sequence is in the category of modules over some commutative ring $A$. Assume further that the map $f : N \to P$ is a surjective $A$-module homomorphism. Then, the kernel of the induced map $\operatorname{Sym} f : \operatorname{Sym} N \to \operatorname{Sym} P$ is the ideal of $\operatorname{Sym} N$ generated by $\operatorname{Ker} f \subseteq N$. (For a proof, see Theorem 62 in [my *A few classical results on tensor, symmetric and exterior powers*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/tensorext.pdf), but I agree -- this is probably somewhere in Bourbaki.) Note that the modules $\operatorname{Sym} N$ and $\operatorname{Sym} P$ are graded, and the induced map $\operatorname{Sym} f : \operatorname{Sym} N \to \operatorname{Sym} P$ is degree-preserving; thus, its kernel is a graded submodule of $\operatorname{Sym} N$. Hence, for each positive integer $i$, the kernel of the induced map $\operatorname{Sym}^i f : \operatorname{Sym}^i N \to \operatorname{Sym}^i P$ is the $i$-th graded component of the kernel of $\operatorname{Sym} f$. Our characterization of the latter kernel thus shows that the kernel of the induced map $\operatorname{Sym}^i f : \operatorname{Sym}^i N \to \operatorname{Sym}^i P$ is spanned by all products of the form $n_1 n_2 \cdots n_i$ with $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_i \in N$ and $n_1 \in \operatorname{Ker} f$.

If $f$ is not surjective, then this no longer holds. For a simple counterexample, set $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $N = \mathbb{Z}$ and $P = \mathbb{Z}/4$ and $f\left(a\right) = \overline{2a}$ (where $\overline{2a}$ means the canonical projection of $2a \in \mathbb{Z}$ onto the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/4$). Then it is easy to see that $\operatorname{Ker} f = 2 \mathbb{Z}$, but $\operatorname{Ker}\left(\operatorname{Sym}^2 f\right)$ is the whole $\operatorname{Sym}^2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So is the proof very nontrivial? I looked in those notes and it looked like the proof was just that it's analagous to another theorem and then the proof of that theorem refers to the proofs of other theorems. Can you maybe write it more explicitly. Essentially, my entire question is just about the proof of Theorem 62

Comment: Oh, woops. That was just a typo. The map should be subjective. Fixed

Comment: Rough sketch: The theorem is easily derived from the analogous property of tensor algebras (Theorem 32). The latter property is, in turn, proven in each rank (Theorem 28) by induction on the rank. The induction step uses the formula $\operatorname{Ker}\left(f \otimes g\right) = \left(\operatorname{Ker} f \right) \otimes W + V \otimes \left(\operatorname{Ker} g\right)$ for the kernel of the tensor product of two surjective maps $f : V \to V'$ and $g : W \to W'$ (Theorem 18). The latter theorem is derived from right-exactness of $\otimes$ using diagram chasing.