# Exact sequence induced by symmetric power of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $k$ be a field, and suppose $0 \to M \to N \to P \to 0$ is an exact sequence of $k$-vector spaces. From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90187), we see that for any $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ the map $$\mathrm{Sym}^r(N) \to \mathrm{Sym}^r(P)$$ is surjective, and in fact we have an exact sequence $$\mathrm{Sym}^{r-1}(N) \otimes M \to \mathrm{Sym}^r(N) \to \mathrm{Sym}^r(P) \to 0$$ where the first map is given by $n_1 \cdots n_{r-1} \otimes m \mapsto n_1 \cdots n_{r-1} m$.

I suspect that we can extend this to get an exact sequence
$$ \cdots \to \mathrm{Sym}^{r-3}(N) \otimes \wedge^3 M \to \mathrm{Sym}^{r-2}(N) \otimes \wedge^2 M \to \mathrm{Sym}^{r-1}(N) \otimes M \to \mathrm{Sym}^r(N) \to \mathrm{Sym}^r(P) \to 0$$
where the map
$$\mathrm{Sym}^{r-i}(N) \otimes \wedge^i(M) \to \mathrm{Sym}^{r-i+1}(N) \otimes \wedge^{i-1}(M)$$
is given by
$$n_1\cdots n_{r-i} \otimes (m_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge m_i) \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^i (-1)^{j+1} n_1\cdots n_{r-i} m_j \otimes (m_1 \wedge \cdots \hat{m_j} \cdots \wedge m_i)$$
where $\hat{m_j}$ means we omit this factor, but I’m having trouble proving or disproving this.

If this is indeed true, I’m guessing it should also be true for free $A$-modules (where $A$ is an arbitrary commutative ring with $1$), but how about for arbitrary $A$-modules?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is the Koszul complex, at least if you replace the symmetric powers of $N$ by the entire symmetric algebra (which amounts to taking a direct sum of your complexes over all $r$s, with appropriate shifts so that you're adding the same exterior powers of $M$ at each level) and regard this symmetric algebra as your new base ring (so it essentially disappears as you tensor $M$ with it).

Comment: Ah, this is an interesting perspective, to view everything as a Koszul complex over $\mathrm{Sym}(N)$. How do we know the resulting Koszul complex is exact except at the final nonzero term, i.e. the $\mathrm{Sym}(N)$ term if we drop the $\mathrm{Sym}(P)$? Also, does this somehow only work for finite free $A$-modules $M$ and $N$ (and maybe even $P$) then?