Analogue of the Koszul complex for symmetric powers?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M$ be a free $R$-module of rank $n$. Let $s: M \rightarrow R$ be a $R$-linear map.
Then, the Koszul complex is a complex
$0 \rightarrow \bigwedge^{n}M \rightarrow \bigwedge^{n-1}M \rightarrow \dots \bigwedge^{2}M \rightarrow M \rightarrow R \rightarrow 0 $
where the differentials are defined in terms of the map $s$.
I was wondering whether there is some analogue of the Koszul complex for symmetric powers?
I am sure that I am not the first person to ask this kind of question, and there must be some literature on this, but a quick google search doesn't come up with much. Intuitively, I do not expect the analogy to be strong, but surely you should be able to say $\textit{something}$ about the case for symmetric powers?
To put my question in context, I was considering the tautological exact sequence on the Grassmannian $Gr^{k,n}$
$1 \rightarrow \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Gr^{k,n}}^{\oplus n} \rightarrow \mathcal{Q} \rightarrow 0 $,
and I was looking at the Koszul complex
$0 \rightarrow \bigwedge^{n-k}\mathcal{R} \rightarrow \bigwedge^{n-k-1}\mathcal{R} \rightarrow \dots \bigwedge^{2}\mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Gr^{k,n}} \rightarrow 0$.
For technical reasons, I want to compare this complex against a complex involving the tautological bundle $\mathcal{Q}$ (aiming for something like a quasi-isomorphism), but I am not even sure whether such a complex involving $\mathcal{Q}$ should exist? My guess is that, if it does exist, it involves symmetric powers of $\mathcal{Q}$, hence my question.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118787/exact-sequence-induced-by-symmetric-power-of-vector-spaces

Have you heard of the BGG correspondence? Tate resolutions have recently been extended to the toric or binomial case, so maybe the grassmannian or trinomial case is tenable.

@Jan-MagnusØkland                                                     No I haven't. Thank you for this remark.

Not an answer, just an extended comment.  The key defining feature of the differential on the Koszul complex is that it $\bigwedge M=\bigoplus_k \bigwedge^{k} M$ is an algebra under the wedge product, and the differential is the unique extension of $s$ which turns $\bigwedge M$ into a differential graded algebra, i.e. the differential satisfies the (graded) product rule, $d(ab)=d(a)b+(-1)^{\deg(a)}ad(b)$.  Because $\bigwedge M$ is graded-commutative, this is enough to guarantee that $d^2=0$.
Unfortunately, in the actual commutative case, this is no longer the case.  For example, if $R=\mathbb R$, and $M=R$, then $\operatorname{Sym}(M)\cong R[x]$, and if $s(x)=1$, then using the product rule to extend $s$ simply gives the ordinary derivative, which does not satisfy $d^2=0$.
This doesn't mean that some other construction cannot work, but the naive attempt at generalization fails.

Thank you for your comment. This is insightful
